# VersionResourceResolver breaks CSS relative URLs

Tags: css, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using a VersionResourceResolver in Spring Boot 1.2.2 for Cache Busting. Unfortunately it thinks it is clever to manipulate URIs specified in CSS files.

Take Twitters Bootstrap for example. It looks for the font in the directory above the directory where the CSS file is located.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Without the VersionResourceResolver it works like expected:

```
GET http://example.com/res/css/bootstrap.min.css
GET http://example.com/res/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

Now I add the VersionResourceResolver:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
            .setCachePeriod(CACHE_SECONDS)
            .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver()                      
                .addFixedVersionStrategy(buildVersion, "/**/"))
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());       
}
```

Now this happens:

```
GET http://example.com/res/085a8/css/bootstrap.min.css
GET http://example.com/res/085a8/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

So, why is this happening? Because someone is tampering with the URI in the CSS file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('085a8/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('085a8/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('085a8/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('085a8/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Bootstrap is just an example. This happens for almost all (strangely not for all) URIs specified in CSS ressources. Using Spring's CssLinkResourceTransformer does not help. So, how do I tell Spring to NOT manipulate the CSS files?

Edit: I figured out, that Spring invokes the CssLinkResourceTransformer. But I did not specify that anywhere. Probably Spring Boot autoconfigures this somewhere.

```
03-05 16:12:47.711 TRACE 11064 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.r.CssLinkResourceTransformer     : Transforming resource: ServletContext resource [/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css]
2015-03-05 16:12:47.716 TRACE 11064 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.r.CssLinkResourceTransformer     : Link modified: 77a6e2aa77283c05d58f4ab52102f55684b6fb04/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot (original: ../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot)
2015-03-05 16:12:47.716 TRACE 11064 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.r.CssLinkResourceTransformer     : Link not modified: ../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix
2015-03-05 16:12:47.717 TRACE 11064 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.r.CssLinkResourceTransformer     : Link modified: 77a6e2aa77283c05d58f4ab52102f55684b6fb04/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 (original: ../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2)
2015-03-05 16:12:47.718 TRACE 11064 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.r.CssLinkResourceTransformer     : Link modified: 77a6e2aa77283c05d58f4ab52102f55684b6fb04/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff (original: ../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff)
2015-03-05 16:12:47.719 TRACE 11064 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.r.CssLinkResourceTransformer     : Link modified: 77a6e2aa77283c05d58f4ab52102f55684b6fb04/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf (original: ../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf)
2015-03-05 16:12:47.719 TRACE 11064 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.r.CssLinkResourceTransformer     : Link not modified: ../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular
```

Edit2: Spring automatically creates a CssLinkResourceTransformer, if you register a RessourceChain -.- . See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceChainRegistration.java#L112

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Resource Handling in Spring 4.1+

The VersionStrategy you're using, [FixedVersionStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/FixedVersionStrategy.html), is tailored for JavaScript module loaders that deal with file names to load JavaScript modules.

Since you're using a JavaScript module loader ([require.js](http://requirejs.org/)), using a [ContentVersionStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ContentVersionStrategy.html) for CSS/images and a [FixedVersionStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/FixedVersionStrategy.html) for JS is more adapted to your application. So changing your configuration to this should fix it:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    VersionResourceResolver versionResolver = new VersionResourceResolver()
            .addFixedVersionStrategy(version, "/**/*.js")
            .addContentVersionStrategy(version, "/**/*.css", "/**/*.png");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
            .setCachePeriod(CACHE_SECONDS)
            .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(versionResolver);
}
```

Note that you don't need to register a `PathResourceResolver` or a `CssLinkResourceTransformer`, as it is done for you by inspecting your configuration (you already figured this out by reading the source code).

Now, to get a better view of that feature, I'd suggest you to read [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/24/spring-framework-4-1-handling-static-web-resources) and to take a look at [this example application](https://github.com/bclozel/spring-resource-handling/).

### SPR-12669 JIRA issue

Actually, this issue has nothing to do with your use case and is not per se a bug. Guillaume created the [WUIC project](https://wuic.github.io/), and we're discussing there ways to better integrate this asset pipeline in Spring projects. So as a framework developer, he's looking for more flexibility for WUIC users - the resource handling feature itself is working properly.

The workaround you're describing is not designed to be used in applications, as you're doing a lot of plumbing manually for no good reason instead of relying on Spring's defaults.

Also, note that the defaults we're discussing here are set by Spring Framework, not by Spring Boot. Spring Boot is "only" [autoconfiguring well-known locations to serve static resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using RequireJS to load my JavaScript modules, therefore I need to use a VersionResourceResolver. This resolver takes the hash from the latest git commit and manipulates my URIs this way: /res/js/require.js to /res/{gitHash}/js/require.js. In the config of RequireJS I set the baseUrl to "/res/{gitHash}/js/". Works perfectly.

The problem is the handling of URLs in CSS files. See original post.

Comment: I've updated my anwser. You can use several version strategies to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is working great :-) I've spent hours yesterday to  get it working... :D

Comment: While avoiding FixedVersionStrategy is a workaround for this issue, I still think CssLinkResourceTransformer shouldn't break relative paths in CSS URLs when using FixedVersionStrategy. Why is FixedVersionStrategy not a good fit for CSS files?

Comment: I wrote up an issue for this behavior of FixedVersionStrategy + CssLinkResourceTransformer: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13727

Comment: @BrianClozel are you familiar with any issues regarding this and 4.3.X? Appears to work with 4.2.5 but when upgrading to 4.3.2 it's failing with "Failed to decode downloaded font" along with "OTS parsing error: invalid version tag". I'm still investigating and might submit a jira ticket

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behavior is, that Spring automatically creates a CssLinkResourceTransformer, if you create a ResourceChain. You can see it in their [sourcecode](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceChainRegistration.java#L112). This is a default configuration in their framework.

Unfortunately in my case it breaks the relative paths in CSS files. In order to avoid the default configuration of the CssLinkResourceTransformer, you need to do the ResourceHandling yourself. For example this [way](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework-issues/blob/master/SPR-12669/src/main/java/org/springframework/issues/config/ResourceConfiguration.java) (not recommended!).

Comment: Daniel, please take a look at my answer - you'll probably want to update that one as it is sending the wrong message to Spring developers. Also, could you update your question with the Spring Framework version you're using? I'm not sure the FixedVersionStrategy should try to update relative paths (this one may be a bug)

Comment: Brian, I updated my original post with the version of Spring Boot I am using. I use the version of the Spring Framework, which Spring Boot provides "automatically". Going to update my above answer, to clarify that is not a "bug".

Comment: it's "breaking" the path of CSS files because you're mapping that FixedVersionStrategy to CSS files as well...

Answer (score 0):

I encounter similar problem with rewriting relative paths in CSS files. I had to disable it because on PROD my application was served on sub-path (I mean like "my.beautiful.app.com/myapproute")

I solve this by creating new class that extends CssLinkResourceTransformer and disables it's transformation. I know, not elegant solution but simple and works.

Here is class that I create:

```
public class CssLinkResourceTransformerDeActivator extends CssLinkResourceTransformer {
@Override
public Resource transform(HttpServletRequest request, Resource resource, ResourceTransformerChain transformerChain)
        throws IOException {
    return transformerChain.transform(request, resource);
}
```

}

Here is my MvcConfig

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**", "/css/**", "/fonts/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/js/", "classpath:/static/css/", "classpath:/static/fonts/")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addTransformer(new CssLinkResourceTransformerDeActivator())
                .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"));
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceUrlEncodingFilter resourceUrlEncodingFilter() {
        return new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter();
    }
}
```